# Difference between "Add Line Comment" and "Toggle Line Comment" in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

What is the difference between them? While I was testing both shortcuts, the behaviour was the same.

**Add Line Comment** or `editor.action.addCommentLine` in Linux is:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

And **Toggle Line Comment** or `editor.action.commentLine` in Linux is:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

Comment: Are you sure `Add Line Comment` is `editor.action.commentLine`? It should be `editor.action.addCommentLine`.

Comment: You are right. I just edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While doing new tests I found a little difference.

Their behaviour are the same in HTML, they just toggle the comment. But in JavaScript it is different. One adds comments, while the other toggle.

So it depends on the language.